# Magento not hitting Varnish cache

Tags: magento, caching, cookies, varnish

I have setup a Magento installation with Nginx behind a Varnish cache server and I'm using [this extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/pagecache-powered-by-varnish.html).

However, I never get a hit on cache:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.1.19
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6
Set-Cookie: frontend=8hoas96a6grd1hfb8vqqa5t9a5; expires=Wed, 12-Jun-2013 16:51:51 GMT; path=/; domain=54.232.214.253; H
ttpOnly
Set-Cookie: currency=BRL; expires=Wed, 12-Jun-2013 16:51:51 GMT; path=/; domain=54.232.214.253; httponly
Set-Cookie: PAGECACHE_ENV=xo32rWZFNbsRL%2F05449a0JLaKEguYZObIG0ZFWOVEV3Ajma1%2FUaj%2FA8nPjnTGpBu%2BMw9h72MUATmZTpHe7Ec4A
9pN%2BJcu%2F%2BggyaAX%2FZEZC4%3D; expires=Wed, 12-Jun-2013 16:51:52 GMT; path=/; domain=54.232.214.253; httponly
X-Cache-Debug: 1
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, s-maxage=0
Expires: Mon, 31 Mar 2008 10:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
X-Purge-URL: /
X-Purge-Host: 54.232.214.253
Date: Wed, 12 Jun 2013 15:51:52 GMT
X-Varnish: 369200976
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
X-Cache: MISS
X-Cache-Expires: Mon, 31 Mar 2008 10:00:00 GMT
```

I understand the reason is because of the cookies being set, so Varnish passes the request on to Nginx, but I can't find the reason it's not removing them from the request (this should be done according to the default.vcl which I'm using the one provided by the module)

Comment: Can you paste the relevant varnish config?  You've got `Set-Cookie` headers (3 of them!), `Cache-Control` headers, a `Pragma` header, *and* an `Expires` header set in the past.  You're going to need a bunch of varnish magic to cache that result.

Comment: @DaveS. I'm using the default 3.0 vcl file that comes with the Varnish Magento module and is working on other installs [link](http://pastebin.com/JWUm7MEf)

Answer (score 0):

Magento is returning a response indicating it that should not be cached. So varnish isn't caching it:

```
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, s-maxage=0
```

You need to return public cache headers (with a positive max-age directive if you like)

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=600
```

and/or an Expires header with a date in the future.

Also, the presence of Set-Cookie headers in the response, if you're using the default.vcl, would also result in the item not being cached:

```
# sub vcl_fetch {
#     if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
#         beresp.http.Set-Cookie ||  /* Look at this line */
#         beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
#       /*
#        * Mark as "Hit-For-Pass" for the next 2 minutes
#        */
#       set beresp.ttl = 120 s;
#       return (hit_for_pass);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to unset the cookies only and you are done in your .vcl file

```
sub vcl_recv {
    unset req.http.cookie;
}

sub vcl_fetch {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
}

sub vcl_deliver {
 unset resp.http.set-cookie;
}
```

OR

If you need to use extension then [follow complete solution posted here](http://rajeshganjeer.wordpress.com/2014/05/28/varnish-with-magento-terpentine/).